# Bottom navigation bar not showing- Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Android and I'm trying to implement the bottom navigation bar. In activity main the navbar appears, but not in the emulator. Below are the MainActivity and ActivityMain files. Thank you for your help!

The MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.androidapp
    
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        
      private lateinit var navController: NavController
    
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
            val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
                 setOf(
                     R.id.photoFragment,
                     R.id.recyclerViewFragment,
                     R.id.settingsFragment
                 )
             )
    
             bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
             setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    
        }
    
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
             return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }
        
}
```

ActivityMain

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_bottom" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Could you please add your `activity_main.xml` file as well?

Comment: @MohammadZarei I just added it

Comment: Found the error! class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  is 2 times. Now it works, but when I click on RecyclerView tab, the app is closing :(

Comment: @oana try to get Log details when app closes